# What is the free $\mathbb{Z}$ module on $M \times N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $M$ and $N$ are left $R$ and right $R$ are modules, what is the free $\mathbb{Z}$ module $F_\mathbb{Z}(M \times N)$.  I don't quite see why this wouldn't be $M \times N$, according to the definition.

Comment: Didn't you ask precisely this already? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296962/what-is-the-free-abelian-group-on-m-times-n-where-m-n-are-modules#comment645592_296962